# How To create On/off button in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am newbie so this question may be sound stupid. I want to load a javascript function using  `<body onload="function()">` but i want to handle this event through on/off switch so if the switch is on(by default) the "onload" event will call the function and if the switch is set to off it will not.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of switch? A switch in the UI? A switch in code?

Comment: You will have to show us the code for how you know if the switch is on or off or tell us what the switch is before we can advise much further.

Comment: Will you be able to touch the switch before the body loads?

Comment: @minitech a switch in UI

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a function when the document is loaded, you should use the
window onload event, or alternatively, and maybe more accepted solution
is to  use  **jquery** (look into it, better learn the best practice from the beginning)

```
$(function(){
    // my_on_load_script;
});
```

If you'd like to create a toggle button in javascript,
you may use jquery (again), to toggle styles applied to the button element
something along the lines:

```
$('#my_button_identifier').click(function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('my_toggled_button_class');
);
```

here you go: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 id="changetext"> status is here</h1>
<button id="alertme" onclick="bulb();" >ON</button>
<script>
var flag = 0;           
            function bulb(){
                if (flag==0) {
                window.alert(flag);
                document.getElementById('alertme').innerHTML = "OFF";
                document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML = "Machine is off";
                flag=1;
                }
                else        {
                window.alert(flag);
                document.getElementById('alertme').innerHTML = "ON";
                document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML = "Machine is on";              
                flag=0;
                }
            }
</script>
```